# Equations of motion with Hamiltonian containing exponential term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem

I don't quite understand how to compute explicitly $q_1 = q_1(t)$ and $p_1 = p_1(t)$ in the following problem, where there is a non-trivial term in the Hamiltonian:

**Problem**

Consider the Hamiltonian
$$
H(q_1, p_1, p_2, q_2) = \frac{1}{2}p_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} q_2^2 p_2^2 + e^{−q_1 q_2 p_2}.
$$
Here $(q_1, q_2)$ and $(p_1, p_2)$ respectively denote Cartesian coordinates and the canonically
conjugate momenta.

1. Find two one-parameter families of symmetries and the associated conserved quantities.
2. Qualitatively describe the motion in the phase space.
3. Compute *explicitly* $q_1 = q_1(t)$ and $p_1 = p_1(t)$ as functions of time and initial conditions.

**Solution attempt**

Point 3. is where the question arises, but I wrote down (almost) the whole solution in detail:

*1. Symmetries and associated conserved quantities*

One symmetry is *time translation symmetry* since for any parameter shift of e.g. $q_1$ we get

$$
q_1(t) \mapsto q_1'(t) = q_1(t + \epsilon) = q_1(t) + \epsilon \dot{q}_1(t) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
$$
yielding
$$
\delta_t q_1(t) = \epsilon \dot{q}_1(t).
$$
The other canonical variables similarly transform.

The symmetries should satisfy for the case of the $(q_1, p_1)$ pair
$$
\delta_t q_1 = \epsilon \frac{\partial Q_t}{\partial p_1}, \qquad
\delta_t p_1 = - \epsilon \frac{\partial Q_t}{\partial q_1}
$$

which is satisfied by $Q_t = H$. Similarly can be said about the $(q_2, p_2)$ pair.

The other symmetry could be
$$
\delta_s q_2 = \epsilon q_2, \qquad \delta_s p_2 = \epsilon p_2.
$$

The corresponding charge could be computed via

$$
\delta_t q_2 = \epsilon \frac{\partial Q_s}{\partial p_2} = \epsilon q_2, \qquad
\delta_t p_2 = - \epsilon \frac{\partial Q_s}{\partial q_2} = \epsilon p_2
$$

Which is satisfied by e.g. $Q_s = q_2 p_2$.

*2. Qualitative description of motion*

I omitted this part because I find it irrelevant to the problem.

*3. Explicit solution of $q_1 = q_1(t)$ and $p_1 = p_1(t)$.*

One can derive the equations of motion by

$$
\dot{q}_1 (t) = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{p_1}} = p_1, \qquad \dot{p}_1 (t) = -\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{q_1}} = p_2(t) q_2(t) e^{-p_2(t) q_2(t) q_1(t)}
$$

Here we know that $p_2(t) q_2(t) = const. =: Q_s$ on shell. Substitution of $p_1 = \dot{q}_1$ gives us

$$
\ddot{q}_1 (t) = Q_s e^{-Q_s q_1(t)}.
$$

Rearranging variables give
$$
\frac{d \dot{q}_1(t)}{dt} e^{Q_s q_1(t)} = Q_s \implies e^{Q_s q_1(t)} d \dot{q}_1(t) = Q_s dt
$$

we can rewrite $d \dot{q}_1(t)$ as $ \ddot{q}_1(t) dt$, so that we can write

$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} e^{Q_s q_1(t)} \ddot{q}_1(t) dt = Q_s (t_1 - t_0),
$$

which leads completely nowhere even after partial integration. What do I get wrong here?

In summary:

**What is the correct explicit formula for $q_1(t)$ and $p_1(t)$?**

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following, but the argument for it might be a bit shaky and it didn't work.

Since $q_2 p_2$ is a constant of motion, and in the Hamiltonian $q_2 p_2$ always appears together, why can't we just drop the dependence of the $(q_2, p_2)$ canonical pairs and rewrite $q_2 p_2 =: \alpha$. Then we acquire

$$
H(q_1, p_1) = \frac{1}{2} p_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 + e^{-q_1 \alpha}
$$

The term $\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2$ can be absorbed into a new Hamiltonian $ K = H - \frac{1}{2}\alpha^2$. Now we have

$$
K(q_1, p_1) = \frac{1}{2} p_1^2 + e^{-q_1 \alpha}.
$$

Equations of motion can be written as
$$
\dot{q}_1 = \frac{\partial K}{\partial p_1} = p_1,\\
\dot{p}_1 = - \frac{\partial K}{\partial q_1} = \alpha e^{-q_1 \alpha},
$$

but this still can't be solved explicitly.

**Source:**

- https://www.math.sissa.it/sites/default/files/Entrance_Examinations_pdf/Scritto2016.pdf

Comment: From $H(q_1,p_1)=\frac{1}{2}p_1^2+e^{-\alpha q_1}$ (dropping the constant piece), you can find $p_1=\sqrt{2(H-e^{-\alpha q_1})}$. $H$ is also a conserved quantity, so treat it as a constant. Then plug in $p_1=\dot{q}_1$, now you can integrate this ODE to get an explicit solution of $q_1(t)$. I've checked that the integration can be done explicitly. I might expand it into an answer when I get time...

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thank you!